# Optimization of scheduling

Tags: statistics, optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

I'm making my first steps in the optimization field. 
The problem I'm trying to solve is as follows:
I'm a TV channel. 
I have n programs that I want to schedule, in a 24-hours day. 
For simplicity, let's assume I have 24 programs, and each is 1-hour long. 
For each program, I have it's predicted ratings for each hour. 
For example, for program A:

```
Program A Ratings:
00:00 2.5%
01:00 2.3%
.
.
.
23:00 3.4%
```

So I have 24 predictions like that, for each program.

Each program should of course be broadcasted once (constraint), 
and the goal is to maximize the overall rating. 
I'm struggling to understand how to write the equation.

I tried to look at "order optimization" - but I don't think this is the right term I'm after.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I tried to find materials about this problem, but I didn't. I also help people a lot on SO, but here I was just stuck, so unfortunately I can not show a lot of fruitful effort I have made.

Comment: It seems to be a typical dynamic programming problem. To determine a maximum cost path along a two dimensional indexed grid.

Comment: This can be formulated as a linear assignment problem, which is a special case of Linear Programming.  Each of 24 programs needs to be assigned to one of the 24 hour slots. The cost matrix to be minimized is the negative of the matrix of ratings forf program i in slot j.